# How speed up count from another table aggregation in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like

```
SELECT ProductId,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                         FROM Log 
                         WHERE Log.App = App.No 
                         AND Log.Event = 54 
                         )
      FROM App
      WHERE App.cat IN (1,2,3)
```

This query returning 1 million records. Problem is this query is really slow. I have compound index for LOG (App, Event) and index for App (cat).Is there any way to speed up this query ?
App and Log tables contains around 10M records

when i comment out `"SELECT COUNT(*) ...."` query is super fast

Comment: You are _counting_ records 1 million times (!). What is the actual response time and what would be your expectation for it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try rewriting your query to use a join instead of a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.ProductId,
       COALESECE(t2.logCount, 0)
FROM App t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t1.No, COUNT(*) AS logCount
    FROM App t1
    LEFT JOIN Log t2
        ON t1.No    = t2.App AND
           t2.Event = 54
    WHERE t1.cat IN (1, 2, 3)
    GROUP BY t1.No
) t2
    ON t1.No = t2.No
```

Comment: What if you perform `inner join` in `inner query` and `left join` on `outer query`, wouldn't it be better?

Comment: @Shaharyar Look closely and you'll see why that isn't desirable.  In the original query, he computes a count for each record, almost like a window function.  Every record in `App` will therefore appear in the result set, even the count is zero.  If we were to `INNER JOIN`, then records from `App` which do not match to anything would be filtered off.  This would change the result set from the OP.

Comment: The outer `INNER JOIN` is OK because there is no chance of any records from `App t1` being filtered off.

Comment: I agree, created a query with my logic. I suppose it'll be little better with this approach in performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JOIN. Because subquery is very slow.

```
 SELECT ProductId, COUNT(Log.*) 
   FROM App
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Log ON Log.App = App.No  AND Log.Event = 54 
  WHERE App.cat IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: This won't give the desired results, because it will produce a single count for the entire query.

Comment: Yes, I wrote that, is can be a sample